# Llenar DropDownListFor con ViewBag - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estoy tratando de llenar un `DropDownListFor` con un `ViewBag` pero no entiendo como colocarlo en mi cshtml, el problema radica en donde colocar el `foreach` para poder iterar el contenido de mi `ViewBag`.

Dejo mi código y espero puedan ayudarme.

Controlador:

```
public ActionResult EditInterview() {
        url = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
        StarInterview = ((HttpRequestWrapper)Request).Url.Segments[3];
        //idInterview = Convert.ToInt32(StarInterview);
        datalist = new DataSet();
        datalist = GeneralFnt.FillTable("Select status from rhInterview where idInterview ='" + Convert.ToInt32(StarInterview) + "' ;");

            datalist = GeneralFnt.FillTable("select rhInterview.idInterview,Suitable,Puesto,Name,RFC,FirstLastname,SecondLastname,Birthday,BirthCity,Stance,Colonia,MaritalStatus,Education,EconomicDependents,Phone,ShoesSize,TshirtSize,JeansSize,InfoFona,Rentry,Date,residence,LaboralExperience,FamiliarDynamic,UnforSeen,Studying, AdditionalBenefits,NumBus,street,MedicalService,comments,company,duration,reason,industryexperience,dynamicfamiliar,studycomments,benefitscomment,issuescomments,residencecomment,unseencomment,cp from rhInterview inner join rhInterviewDetails on rhInterview.idInterview = rhInterviewDetails.idInterview inner join tblRHBusStop on rhInterview.Route = tblRHBusStop.BusId inner join [rhInterviewcomments] on [rhInterviewcomments].idinterview = rhInterview.idInterview where rhInterview.idInterview='" + Convert.ToInt32(StarInterview) + "' ;");

            var Model = datalist.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(user => new rhInterviewDetails()
            {
                idInterview = user.Field<int>("idInterview"),
                Name = user.Field<string>("Name"),
                FirstLastname = user.Field<string>("FirstLastname"),
                SecondLastname = user.Field<string>("SecondLastname"),
                RFC = user.Field<string>("RFC"),
                Birthday = user.Field<DateTime>("Birthday"),
                BirthCity = user.Field<string>("BirthCity"),
                Stance = user.Field<int>("Stance"),
                Colonia = user.Field<string>("Colonia"),
                MaritalStatus = user.Field<string>("MaritalStatus"),
                Education = user.Field<string>("Education"),
                EconomicDependents = user.Field<string>("EconomicDependents"),
                Phone = user.Field<string>("Phone"),
                ShoesSize = user.Field<string>("ShoesSize"),
                TshirtSize = user.Field<string>("TshirtSize"),
                JeansSize = user.Field<string>("JeansSize"),
                residence = user.Field<Boolean>("residence"),
                LaboralExperience = user.Field<Boolean>("LaboralExperience"),
                unseencomment = user.Field<string>("unseencomment"),
                FamiliarDynamic = user.Field<Boolean>("FamiliarDynamic"),
                UnforSeen = user.Field<Boolean>("UnforSeen"),
                Studying = user.Field<Boolean>("Studying"),
                AdditionalBenefits = user.Field<Boolean>("AdditionalBenefits"),

                NumBus = user.Field<string>("Numbus"),
                Street = user.Field<string>("Street"),
                MedicalService = user.Field<string>("MedicalService"),
                comments = user.Field<string>("comments"),
                company = user.Field<string>("company"),
                duration = user.Field<string>("duration"),
                reason = user.Field<string>("reason"),
                industryexperience = user.Field<string>("industryexperience"),
                dynamicfamiliar = user.Field<string>("dynamicfamiliar"),

                studycomments = user.Field<string>("studycomments"),
                benefitscomment = user.Field<string>("benefitscomment"),

                issuescomments = user.Field<string>("issuescomments"),

                residencecomment = user.Field<string>("residencecomment"),
                cp = user.Field<int>("cp"),
                Suitable = user.Field<string>("Suitable"),
                Puesto = user.Field<string>("Puesto"),
            });
            var list = Model.ToList();

          datalist = GeneralFnt.FillTable("select BusId, NumBus, street, reference from tblRHBusStop");
            var ModelOperation = datalist.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(user => new RhBus {
                BusId= user.Field<int>("BusId"),
                NumBus = user.Field<string>("NumBus"),
                Street = user.Field<string>("street"),
                Reference = user.Field<string>("reference"),
            });
            var MOperation = ModelOperation.ToList();
            ViewBag.Operation = MOperation;
            return View(list);
        }
        }
```

Asi es como lo estoy agregando a mi vista pero marca el error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." al parecer es por que no se esta enviando. Y sobre el dropdown list desconozco totalmente como obtener los elementos de mi lista.

```
 @foreach (var OperationM in ViewBag.Operation)
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model)
                    {@Html.DropDownListFor(x => OperationM., new SelectList(ViewBag.Operacion, "Value", "Text"), " -Seleccione una  ruta-", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "select-buscadorRHBus" }) }}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme.
Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Hola. Que campos de `RhBus` quieres que tenga el `DropDownListFor`?. Recuerda que debe ser un `Value` y un  `Text`. También indica en la pregunta el  Modelo `RhBus`.